# Kotlin - Internet and location permissions problem

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, location

Ι am writing an android application that uses both location and internet connection permissions and I am running it on my tablet.  As you can see, I have included both in the manifest file. The problem is that when OnConnected() function is called the below **if** in the **MainActivity.kt** evaluates to true and I can't proceed further in the function.   So can you give me some hint to provide some more code if it is not relevant

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

MainActivity.kt

```
override fun onConnected(p0: Bundle?) {
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        return;
    }
//some code 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand the logic behind permissions in Android. Just adding the permissions in the manifest, doesn't mean that the user has authorized the application to do what those permissions enable.

If your if condition evaluates to true, since those permissions are not granted, you have to ask the user for those permissions.

Android has a some good [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) on how to this.

I highly suggest you go over that.

Comment: I have two applications , one that access the location and one that access the internet. In the first one I have the code without the Request you speak about and the location displayed succesfully in the screen when I open the location of the phone. Sorry that I didn't know but the reason is the above.

Comment: @michalischaviaras - I don't really understand your comment. What do you mean when you say " the reason is the above"? In some Android versions, when downloading an application, it asks you before installing to approve permissions.

Answer (score 0):

From Android 6.0 onwards needs to request permission the best way is to do a permissionManager Class to Handle that and then check in your Activity if the user has accepted the permissions:

```
 class PermissionManager private constructor() {

   fun checkPermission(
    activity: Activity,
    permissionRequests: Array<String>?,
    requestCode: Int
): Boolean {

    permissionRequests?.let {
        it.firstOrNull {
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                activity,
                it
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        }?.apply {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                permissionRequests,
                requestCode
            )
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

companion object {
    val instance by lazy { PermissionManager() }
    const val CAMERA_PERMISSION = 1
}
```

}

Then in your activity check the permission Result:

```
   class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
       override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ar)
    //If the user has the permission accepted the next times
        if (PermissionManager.instance.checkPermission(
            this, arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA
            ), PermissionManager.CAMERA_PERMISSION
        )
        ) {
            initLogic()
        }
    }
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    when (requestCode) {
        PermissionManager.CAMERA_PERMISSION -> {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                initLogic()
            } else {
                return
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```